# Allowing and/or not allowing public access to web site folder

Tags: php

I have a website which contains an embedded audio player or jukebox. The jukebox accesses recordings located in a "media" folder. If you type in the URL: www.mywebsite.com/media you can see all the recordings that have been put in there and you can copy them as well.

I am trying to figure a way where anyone can use the jukebox and listen to the recordings but cannot go to www.mywebsite.com/media and have access to the files in the folder. If I password protect the media folder then when using the jukebox to listen to music a prompt will come up asking for a user id and password'

Is there a way to do this using php?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Perhaps you could advise a different way to ask my question to fit within the rules. I have a website with all of it's folders located on the Yahoo server host. Anyone, anywhere can type in www.mywebsiteName.com/media and access all of the music recordings in there. I'm trying to make that folder not accessible yet still be able to run my website without a requirement for the visitor to "Log in". What kind of details can I add to all that so that it fits within the forum guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are many ways, but PHP probably isn't the best way. Here's a short list:

1. Put an index.html or index.php file in the directory, with nothing in it except a "nooop" message.
2. Put a .htaccess file in the directory and add `Options -Indexes` to it.
3. Create a redirect rule in a higher-level .htaccess file, disallowing the exact path

1 is probably the simplest.

Of course, if they know the name of the file, this won't stop them from accessing it directly. This will just stop them being able to see the whole list.

Comment: rjdown, thanks for your reply. Could you please expound a bit? Not sure what  "nooop" message means. Index.html is my home page. How would replacing it with a page that would display a "nooop" message accomplish what I am trying to do? Because my site is hosted by Yahoo I cannot use an .htaaccess file. At least that's what they told me. Thanks again! There must be a way to do this.

Comment: Haha... by "nooop" I just meant a message to the user saying that access to the directory listing is forbidden. When a user hits a directory, the server checks to see if there is a page it should show, instead of the list of files. It depends on the config, but it will usually look for files in the same directory called index.html, index.htm, index.php. If one of these files exists, the user gets that, otherwise they get a list of all the files.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question back in August. I apologize for not check marking your answer sooner. Am new to the forum and am just now beginning to become familiar with how it is run and how to enter comments. It would be helpful if there was a video tutorial showing examples on how to enter comments effectively and correctly following the rules and procedures outlined in the help section. I'll check YouTube. Thanks again for helping me. Dan